# To Clarify my insights to copy initialization and direct initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-constructor, copy-initialization

Define a class as follows:

```
class A {
public:
  A(): s("") {}                             //default constructor
  A(const char* pStr): s(pStr) {}           //constructor with parameter
  A(const A& a) : s(a.s) {}                 //copy constructor
  ~A() {}                                   //destructor
private:
  std::string s;
};
```

The code below will execute direct initialization:

```
A a1("Hello!");   //direct initialization by calling constructor with parameter
A a2(a1);          //direct initialization by calling copy constructor
```

And what follows will execute copy initialization:

```
A a3 = a1;  
A a4 = "Hello!";
```

To my understanding, `A a4 = "Hello"` is equivalent to:

```
//create a temporary object first, then "copy" this temporary object into a4 by calling copy constructor    
A temp("Hello!");    
A a4(temp);
```

So what is the difference between `A a3 = a1` and `A a2(a1)`? It seems they both call copy constructor. And whether are my comments above right? (given no compiler optimization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between [direct-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) and [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization#Notes):

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.

So if you make the copy constructor `explicit` then `A a3 = a1` won't work; while `A a2(a1)` still works fine.

Comment: Well, and is my understanding on case `A a4 = "Hello"` right without any compiler optimization?

Comment: @Finley Yes, it's right. With optimization, the copy constructor is usually optimized.

Comment: @Finley Since C++17 `A a4 = "Hello";` is exactly the same as `A a4("Hello");`,  other than the `explicit` check